# I need to know how to set a variable to this value in Java

Tags: java

---

```
       **NEVERMIND, I CHEATED**
```

---

```
Movie[] movies = new Movie[8];
movies[0] = new Movie("The Godfather", 1972);
```

Say I have a bunch of movies variables, how could I set a variable (call it year or something) to the year in the movies[] variable?

(im in a programming class and my assignment was to debug a file, my only error left is that i need to make the year variable set to the year in movies[])

Heres my complete code:

```
import javax.swing.*;
public class DebugNine2
{
public static void main(String[] args)
   {
  Movie[] movies = new Movie[8];
  Movie[] year;
  int i;
  String message, entry;
  movies[0] = new Movie("The Godfather", 1972);
  movies[1] = new Movie("The Good, the Bad, and the Ugly", 1966);
  movies[2] = new Movie("Pulp Fiction", 1994);
  movies[3] = new Movie("Shindler's List", 1993);
  movies[4] = new Movie("Casablanca", 1942);
  movies[5] = new Movie("Wizard of Oz", 1939);
  movies[6] = new Movie("Citizen Kane", 1941);
  movies[7] = new Movie("Some Like It Hot", 1959);
  entry = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,
    "Sort Movies by\n(N)ame, or (Y)ear");
  if(entry.equals("N"))
  {
     nameSort(movies);
     message = "Sorted by Name\n";
  }
  else
  {
      year=movies;
      yearSort(year);
      message = "Sorted by Year\n";
  }   
  display(movies, message);
  //System.out.println(movies+"\n"+message);
}
public static void nameSort(Movie[] array)
{
  int a, b;
  int highSub = array.length - 1;
  for(a = 0; a < highSub; ++a)
  {
     for(b = 0; b < highSub; ++b)
 {
         String first = array[b].getName();
         String second = array[b + 1].getName();
         if(first.compareTo(second) > 0)
     {

        Movie temp = array[b];
        array[b] = array[b + 1];
        array[b + 1] = temp;
     }
  }
   }
}
public static void yearSort(Movie[] array)
{
    int a, b;
    Movie temp;
    int highSub = array.length;
    for (a = 0; a < highSub; ++a)
    {
       for (b = 0; b < highSub; ++b)
       if (array[b].getYear() > array[b + 1].getYear())
       {
          temp = array[b];
          array[b] = array[b + 1];
          array[b + 1] = temp;
       }
    }
 }
 public static void display(Movie[] s,  String msg)
 {
    for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
       msg = msg + s[i].getName() + ", " + s[i].getYear() + "\n";
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, msg);
 }
}
```

additionally, there is a file called Movie.java which contains the code

```
public class Movie
{
private String name;
private int year;
Movie(String s, int y)
{
  name = s;
  year = y;
}
public String getName()
{ 
  return name;
}
public int getYear()
{
  return year;
}
}
```

Comment: depends on if you have a getter for the year variable or if the year variable is public and so on

Comment: I'm having real trouble understanding what you want to do - plus, there is quite a lot wrong with your current code

Comment: The code you really need to consider (and show us) is the definition of the `Movie` class.

Comment: Now looking at the code, what method do you think you could call to **get** the **Year**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Movie class can have String name and int year fields.Get their setter and getter method.
Initialize them by constructor like
new Movie(String name , int year);

Comment: i honestly have no idea what im doing here, this is my second day on the chapter, none of the samples had anything related to this, im hoping there will be something in the programming exercises but i need to finish the debug assignments first

Answer (score 0):

You can't set the year of the movie objects since the variable is private.
You need to create a public method that changes the value or make the variable itself public.

Comment: i added 

    Movie[] year;
myself, it removed one of the errors i had which was 'variable years not found'